# How to incorporate html file in body of Blastula email

Tags: r, r-markdown, blastula

I am using RMarkdown to generate html files weekly for reports I am making. I would like to be able to send the emails using Blastula incorporating the html file.

Currently, I can create an email object like the following:

```
email <- compose_email(body = md("Here is your report")) %>%
  add_attachment(myHTMLFile)
```

but I'd like to incorporate the html file within the body of the email. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success incorporating [glue](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) while using Blastula.

So your code might looks something like this:

```
content_to_add <- read_file("myHTMLFile.html")

email <- compose_email(body = md(glue("Here is your report.
                                      {content_to_add}")))
```